# Search a table based on the value of more than one cell per row

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, range

I am trying to find a previous value of a unit ( the data for the unit being an entire row) entered into a table. Over time the value in one of the columns in the unit grows and I am attempting to use a loop to analyze each row based on two values in each row and return the previous value in that specific unit when a new value is entered for that specific unit.

```
'My Variables

    Dim current_size As Integer
    Dim last_size As String
    Dim joint_number As Integer

    Dim tool_sizes As Range: Set tool_sizes = drill_log.Range("Drill_Log[Tool Size]")
    Dim joints As Range: Set joints = drill_log.Range("Drill_Log[Joint '#]")
    Dim pass_types As Range: Set pass_types = drill_log.Range("Drill_Log[Pass Type]")
    Dim row As Range

    'Finds the current pass size and last pass size and assigns it to the current pass size variables
        If pass_type = ream Then
            current_size = drill_log.Range("W" & last_ream_range.row)
            joint_number = drill_log.Range("C" & last_ream_range.row)

        ElseIf pass_type = intersect_ream Then
            current_size = drill_log.Range("W" & last_intersect_ream_range.row)
            joint_number = drill_log.Range("C" & last_intersect_ream_range.row)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

    'Finds the previous pass size for the last joint entered

        For Each row In drill_log.Range("Drill_Log")

'Line that Errors
          If pass_types.Value = pass_type And joints.Value = joint_number Then
          If tool_sizes < current_size Then
                    last_size = tool_sizes
                Else
                    last_size = "NONE"
                End If
            Else
            End If

        Next row
```

My goal is to have it examine the specified columns in each row and if it is a match then assign it to the variable if the cell in the column containing the information is less that the current.

Right now it is telling me that I have a type mismatch and I cant solve it. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which line errors?

Comment: Sorry the "If pass_types.Value = pass_type And joints.Value = joint_number Then" Line.  9th from he bottom

Comment: You don't appear to have defined (or declared) `pass_type`. Are they both single-cell ranges?

Comment: there is about 200 lines of code outside of this. The variables that aren't defined are assigned elsewhere. pass_type is a string.

Comment: I am assuming that the ranges declared in my variables are automatically assumed by the program to be referencing the row it is currently on. right?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: If you have a procedure that's over 200 lines of code, consider splitting it up into smaller chunks. e.g. anytime you have a comment that says "this code does XYZ", you should have a separate procedure/function *named* `DoXYZ` - comments say *why*, the *code* says *what*.

Answer (score 2):

A *type mismatch* error on an instruction that compares `Range.Value` against a string or number or anything, is almost certainly due to `Range.Value` containing an error value.

Either fix the data and ensure there can never be an error in these cells:

```
=IFERROR([whatever formula you have here], "")
```

Or change the code so that it no longer assumes there can't be errors in the cells:

```
If Not IsError(pass_types.Value) And Not IsError(joints.Value) Then
    If pass_types.Value = pass_type And joints.Value = joint_number Then
        '...
    End If
End If
```

...or play safe, and do both wherever possible.

---

The reason for the *type mismatch* is that when `IsError(Range.Value)` is `True`, then the type of `Range.Value` is `Variant/Error`, and VBA doesn't know how to compare an `Error` value to anything.

Repro:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(CVErr(xlErrNA))       'prints "Error"
Debug.Print IsError(CVErr(xlErrNA))        'prints "True"
Debug.Print CVErr(xlErrNA)) = vbNullString 'type mismatch
Debug.Print CVErr(xlErrNA)) = 0            'type mismatch
```